# How prove this polynomial inequality from a book

Tags: polynomials

**Question:**

> Let $$f(X)=(X-x_{1})(X-x_{2})\cdots (X-x_{n})$$ be an irreducible polynomial over the field of rational numbers,with integer coefficients and real zeros.
>
> Prove that
> $$\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|x_{i}-x_{j}|\ge\dfrac{n^n}{n!}$$

This result is fell interesting, and  This problem is from problem book, and this problem is  name Siegel created it, and I searched sometimes and can't find it.and can't solve this problem, can someone help me?
[image]

Comment: See Siegel's book "Lectures on the geometry of numbers" (pages 27 and 28).

Comment: Here is [Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=VA2W-dl78UYC&pg=PA27) to the reference given by Lucia. I would be quite curious to know the name of the book where you saw this problem.

Comment: @MartinSleziak,is from ：Problems From the Book  by Titu Andreescu Page 312

Comment: Is this perhaps related to the Van der Waerden conjecture (now theorem) on the end of this page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix

Comment: Not sure why there is a bounty when Lucia already gave an answer; perhaps another place to look would be Goldman's [**The Queen of Mathematics**](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Queen-Mathematics-Historically-Motivated/dp/toc/1568810067) in which you will find the same result. See Chapter 22 pp. 461-462 ([**here**](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/hs2014/beweise-aus-dem-buch/goldman-queen-of-mathematics-chapter22.pdf#11)) in which the result is discussed as a special case of Minkowski's proof of a conjecture due to Kronecker.